# Layered keypresses in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

There are two colors on either side of the screen.
I'd like to be able to use the left arrow to select the left half of the screen, and then use the up and down arrows to manipulate the color until satisfied.

Yet, my current code not work. The problem appears to be with the need for a sequence of key commands, i.e., left arrow, then up and down to manipulate color.

```
red = (100, 0, 0)
green = (0, 100, 0)
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
dw2 = display_width/2
calibration_exit = False

while not calibration_exit:

        pygame.event.pump()
        pygame.draw.rect( screen,  red,   [  0   , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
        pygame.draw.rect( screen,  green, [ dw2  , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
        pygame.display.update()

        # Get Keys #
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[K_LEFT]:

            while not keys[K_RIGHT]:

                keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

                if keys[K_UP]:
                    red = list(red)
                    red[0] += 10
                    red = tuple(red)
                    pygame.draw.rect( screen,  red,   [  0   , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
                    pygame.display.update()


                if keys[K_DOWN]:
                    red = list(red)
                    red[0] -= 10
                    red = tuple(red)
                    pygame.draw.rect( screen,  red,   [  0   , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
                    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: use left arrow to set `left_side = True/False` and later check `left_side` when you press right arrow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it as you only being able to call `pygame.key.get_pressed()` once per frame, and `pygame.display.update()` once per frame, etc. You can't do your standard if then if then logic, since you 'start' at the root of the `while` loop each time. This means you have to track your state separately. Something like:

```
calibration_exit = False
selected = None
while not calibration_exit:
    pygame.event.pump()
    pygame.draw.rect( screen,  red,   [  0   , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
    pygame.draw.rect( screen,  green, [ dw2  , 0, dw2, display_height ] )
    pygame.display.update()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        selected = "left"
    if keys[K_RIGHT]:
        selected = "right"

    if selected == "left":
        if keys[K_UP]:
            # modify 'left' by going up
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            # modify 'left' by going down
    elif selected == "right":
        if keys[K_UP]:
            # modify 'right' by going up
        if keys[K_DOWN]:
            # modify 'right' by going down
```

Comment: I just thought of this about 5 seconds before you posted! Of course. Thank you for the answer!